# Package inputenc error

Tags: fonts

`inputenc` is not designed for XeTeX. How could I resolve this problem please? I need two languages: Greek and Catalan. I have a MacBook Pro and I work with El Capitan and TeXShop 3.58.

Comment: Package name is `inputenc`.

Comment: You don't need `inputenc` with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

You just don't need `inputenc` with XeLaTeX. Just be sure your file is UTF-8 encoded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{catalan}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\begin{document}

Barcelona és una ciutat i metròpoli a la costa mediterrània de la península Ibèrica. És la capital de 
Catalunya, essent-ho tant de la comunitat autònoma com de la província de Barcelona i de la comarca del 
Barcelonès, i la segona ciutat en població i pes econòmic de l'Estat espanyol i de la península 
ibèrica. El municipi creix sobre una plana encaixada entre la serralada Litoral, el mar Mediterrani, 
el riu Besòs i la muntanya de Montjuïc. La ciutat acull les seus de les institucions d'autogovern més 
importants de Catalunya: la Generalitat de Catalunya i el Parlament de Catalunya. Per haver estat capital 
del Comtat de Barcelona, rep sovint el sobrenom de Ciutat Comtal.

Amb una població d'1.602.386 habitants (2014), Barcelona és la ciutat més poblada del Principat i 
l'onzena de la Unió Europea, segona ciutat no capital d'estat després d'Hamburg. És el principal nucli 
urbà de la regió metropolitana de Barcelona, que aglutina 5.012.961 habitants, i de l'àrea 
Metropolitana de Barcelona, integrada per 36 municipis, que té una població de 3.225.058 habitants i 
una superfície de 633 km². Un estudi del departament d'Afers Socials i Econòmics de l'ONU de l'any 2005 
situa Barcelona en la posició 51 del rànquing de les poblacions amb major nombre d'habitants del món.

\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
Η Βαρκελώνη (στα καταλανικά και τα ισπανικά Barcelona, 'Μπαρσελόνα' και 'Μπαρθελόνα' αντίστοιχα) είναι 
πόλη της Ισπανίας, πρωτεύουσα της Αυτοδιοικούμενης Περιφέρειας της Καταλωνίας. Σήμερα αποτελεί τη δεύτερη 
σημαντικότερη πόλη του Ισπανικού κράτους όσον αφορά τον πληθυσμό και την οικονομία μετά την Μαδρίτη. Η 
μητροπολιτική της περιοχή έχει έναν πληθυσμό της τάξης των 5 εκατομμυρίων κατοίκων, από τα οποία τα 4,5 
εκατομμύρια ζούνε ειδικότερα στους 36 δήμους της αστικής της περιοχής, κάτι που την κάνει τη μεγαλύτερη 
μητρόπολη του ευρύτερου μεσογειακού χώρου.

Η πόλη έχει μακρά ιστορία. Η σημερινή πόλη ιδρύθηκε κατά τον πρώτο αιώνα στην θέση του παλαιοϊβηρικού 
Μπάρκενο και ονομάστηκε από τους Ρωμαίους Colonia Iulia Augusta Paterna Faventia Barcino. Κατά τον 2ο 
αιώνα χτίστηκαν τείχη και η πόλη άρχισε να μεγαλώνει ως τμήμα της ρωμαϊκής επαρχίας που είχε όμως 
πρωτεύουσα την Tarraco, σημερινή Ταρραγόνα.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

[image]